# Drupal 7, how to add a "last updated" function on my site?

Tags: drupal-7

I wish to add a "Last updated" on my web site (a text automatically showing when my site's content was last up dated).

I found some answers on Drupal forum, unfortunately they all concern Drupal 6 and I simply couldn't get them to work on Drupal 7...

Since I know about nothing about PHP, and I belive it requires to add some PHP code, thank you very much if the answer could be "as simple as possible", and very "step by step" :o)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you need to display the last updated date of ANY content on site (i.e. no matter which piece of content was updated - you display this date) or for every piece of content (node)? The answer on second is below.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Muhammad's answer I was able to get this to work in Drupal 6. I just needed to modify a little.

```
<?php print "Last modified date: " . format_date($node->changed, $type = 'small'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the node.tpl.php template and use the following line

```
<?php
    print "Last modified date: " . format_date($node->changed, "short");
?>
```

Hope this helps... Muhammad.

Answer (score 0):

Not all template files always have a `$node` object in scope (e.g. `page.tpl.php` when used to render the user page does not).

If, for instance, you want to the "Last modified date" line into `page.tpl.php` to have it the page footer, you need to make sure that you only call `format_date` when there is a `$node` object in scope.

This is how this should look like for Drupal 7:

```
<?php
if (isset($node->changed)) {
  print "Last modified date: " . format_date($node->changed);
}
?>
```